# Meaning of square root in this situation

Tags: functions

I wasn't someone who really paid attention in math class but grew very fond of it throughout the time I was out of school.

Square Root = A number that produces a specified quantity when multiplied by itself is my understanding.

Ok so basically for this game I'm working on, I need to determine when the player enters the touch distance of a monster.

In order to get distance Y and distanceX, I needed to evaulate the positions first of both the player and the monster.

CharY = 150 ( Y Axis )
CharX = 120 ( X Axis )

```
   Y 
   - 
   - 150
   -
```

X ------ 
   120

Let's say the Monster's starting position is 160 for Y and 150 for X.

Now we have these values
CharY = 150
CharX = 120

MonstY = 160
MonstX = 150

We would first need to calculate the distance between each other. 
DistanceY = CharY - Monst Y
DistanceX = CharX - Monst X
var touchDistance = 30

The touchDistance is the amount of space between the player and monster that we want to allow.

Now we have the distance between them on both axis.  First we make a if statement in order to state for something to happen if both touch and nothing if they aren't.

if ( Math.sqrt(distanceY * distanceY + distanceX + distanceX) < touchDistance ){
                Player has touched

```
        } else {
            Not Touching
        }
```

What I don't understand is this line of code precisely.
Math.sqrt(distanceY * distanceY + distanceX + distanceX) < touchDistance

Could someone explain what that line of math means?

Comment: Hint: [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). Draw it on paper, and note that `distanceX` and `distanceY` are the sides of a right triangle whose hypothenuse is the distance between the player and the monster.

Comment: That is code representing the formula for the distance between two points in an (x, y) plane.   You have already computed the distance for each coordinate so the distance between the two points is the square root of the sum of their squares.

Answer (score 0):

"if ( Math.sqrt(distanceY * distanceY + distanceX + distanceX) < touchDistance )"

It's a typo.  It should be:

"if ( Math.sqrt(distanceY * distanceY + distanceX * distanceX) < touchDistance )"

It's very basic.  The distance between X and Y is the the square root of the the square of the horizontal distance plus the square of the vertical distance.

In other words.  If Y is at a point (a,b) on a grid and X is at a point (0,0) on a grid, the distance, D, between them will be $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

This is because the horizontal distance, a, makes a base of a right triangle.  The vertical distance, b, makes a second leg.  So total distance, D, make a hypotenuse and $D^2 = a^2 + b^2$ or $D =  \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

This is the basis of just about *all* analytic geometric, graphic, metric, etc.  It's *extremely* well known.